# How to create the mongodb schema for below Json?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0e77f4b7368f14c088f542"),
    "folderName" : "team 4",
    "tag" : "search",
    "ismainFolder" : true,
    "innerFolder" : [
                    {
                       parentfolderId" : null,
                      "ismainFolder" : false,
                      "foldername" : "Onkar 11"
                        "subinnerFolder" : [
                                        {
                                            "parentfolderId" : null,
                                            "ismainFolder" : false,
                                            "foldername" : "Onkar 11"
                                            "thirdSubFolder" : [
                                                        {
                                                            "parentfolderId" : null,
                                                            "ismainFolder" : false,
                                                           "foldername" : "Onkar 11"
                                                        }, 
                                                        {
                                                             "parentfolderId" : null,
                                                             "ismainFolder" : false,
                                                             "foldername" : "Onkar 11"
                                                        }
                                                    ] 
                                        }, 

                                   ]
                    },
                ]
}
```

I need to create the mongodb schema for below json format so that innerFolder, subinnerFolder, etc (inner folder structure goes nested) so please help me in this ?

Comment: are you using json-schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of schema in *Mongoose* style.
The only difficulty here is with null value.
One of your possibility is to store it as text,
but consider to do not store null value at all.

```
const detailFolder = {
  parentfolderId: { type: String, default: null },
  ismainFolder: Boolean,
  foldername: String
}

const schema = {
  folderName: String,
  tag: String,
  ismainFolder: Boolean,
  innerFolder: [{
    detailFolder,
    subinnerFolder: [{
      detailFolder,
      thirdSubFolder: [ detailFolder ]
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: How i can add these details in nodejs by using above schema ?

Comment: You can have a look at Mongoose's [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Below is a json schema generated by https://jsonschema.net/#/. You can edit it as required. For Mongoose schema, take a look at https://github.com/topliceanu/mongoose-gen

```
{
  "definitions": {}, 
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#", 
  "$id": "http://example.com/example.json", 
  "type": "object", 
  "properties": {
    "folderName": {
      "$id": "/properties/folderName", 
      "type": "string", 
      "title": "The Foldername Schema.", 
      "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.", 
      "default": "", 
      "examples": [
        "team 4"
      ]
    }, 
    "tag": {
      "$id": "/properties/tag", 
      "type": "string", 
      "title": "The Tag Schema.", 
      "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.", 
      "default": "", 
      "examples": [
        "search"
      ]
    }, 
    "ismainFolder": {
      "$id": "/properties/ismainFolder", 
      "type": "boolean", 
      "title": "The Ismainfolder Schema.", 
      "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.", 
      "default": false, 
      "examples": [
        true
      ]
    }, 
    "innerFolder": {
      "$id": "/properties/innerFolder", 
      "type": "array", 
      "items": {
        "$id": "/properties/innerFolder/items", 
        "type": "object", 
        "properties": {
          "parentfolderId": {
            "$id": "/properties/innerFolder/items/properties/parentfolderId", 
            "type": "null", 
            "title": "The Parentfolderid Schema.", 
            "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.", 
            "default": null, 
            "examples": [
              null
            ]
          }, 
          "ismainFolder": {
            "$id": "/properties/innerFolder/items/properties/ismainFolder", 
            "type": "boolean", 
            "title": "The Ismainfolder Schema.", 
            "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.", 
            "default": false, 
            "examples": [
              false
            ]
          }, 
          "foldername": {
            "$id": "/properties/innerFolder/items/properties/foldername", 
            "type": "string", 
            "title": "The Foldername Schema.", 
            "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.", 
            "default": "", 
            "examples": [
              "Onkar 11"
            ]
          }, 
          "subinnerFolder": {
            "$id": "/properties/innerFolder/items/properties/subinnerFolder", 
            "type": "array", 
            "items": {
              "$id": "/properties/innerFolder/items/properties/subinnerFolder/items", 
              "type": "object", 
              "properties": {
                "parentfolderId": {
                  "$id": "/properties/innerFolder/items/properties/subinnerFolder/items/properties/parentfolderId", 
                  "type": "null", 
                  "title": "The Parentfolderid Schema.", 
                  "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.", 
                  "default": null, 
                  "examples": [
                    null
                  ]
                }, 
                "ismainFolder": {
                  "$id": "/properties/innerFolder/items/properties/subinnerFolder/items/properties/ismainFolder", 
                  "type": "boolean", 
                  "title": "The Ismainfolder Schema.", 
                  "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.", 
                  "default": false, 
                  "examples": [
                    false
                  ]
                }, 
                "foldername": {
                  "$id": "/properties/innerFolder/items/properties/subinnerFolder/items/properties/foldername", 
                  "type": "string", 
                  "title": "The Foldername Schema.", 
                  "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.", 
                  "default": "", 
                  "examples": [
                    "Onkar 11"
                  ]
                }, 
                "thirdSubFolder": {
                  "$id": "/properties/innerFolder/items/properties/subinnerFolder/items/properties/thirdSubFolder", 
                  "type": "array", 
                  "items": {
                    "$id": "/properties/innerFolder/items/properties/subinnerFolder/items/properties/thirdSubFolder/items", 
                    "type": "object", 
                    "properties": {
                      "parentfolderId": {
                        "$id": "/properties/innerFolder/items/properties/subinnerFolder/items/properties/thirdSubFolder/items/properties/parentfolderId", 
                        "type": "null", 
                        "title": "The Parentfolderid Schema.", 
                        "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.", 
                        "default": null, 
                        "examples": [
                          null
                        ]
                      }, 
                      "ismainFolder": {
                        "$id": "/properties/innerFolder/items/properties/subinnerFolder/items/properties/thirdSubFolder/items/properties/ismainFolder", 
                        "type": "boolean", 
                        "title": "The Ismainfolder Schema.", 
                        "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.", 
                        "default": false, 
                        "examples": [
                          false
                        ]
                      }, 
                      "foldername": {
                        "$id": "/properties/innerFolder/items/properties/subinnerFolder/items/properties/thirdSubFolder/items/properties/foldername", 
                        "type": "string", 
                        "title": "The Foldername Schema.", 
                        "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.", 
                        "default": "", 
                        "examples": [
                          "Onkar 11"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How i can do it in mongo db ? var mainFolder = new RepositorySchema({});

var subFolder = new RepositorySchema();

var subsubFolder = new RepositorySchema();

mainFolder.innerFolders.add(subFolder
subFolder.innerFolders.add(subsubFolder);